# SQL: Joining 3 table in SQL, Return the earliest date and the date is not null

Tags: sql

I'm new in SQL. Will need you guys provide me some guide.
I have join 2 table to get the container information and would like to join another table in order to get the date. Here's the code for the first join.

```
Select a.ConsolNumber, a.ConsolType,a.ConsolTransport,b.Container_20F,b.Container_20R,b.Container_20H, b.Container_40F,b.DeliveryMode
FROM ConsolHeader a 
LEFT Join Containers b on a.Consolnumber = b.Consolnumber
```

For the second join, here's come with a trickle part which some of the consolnumber having few transit.

For example

```
|ConsolNumber| ETD     |
|------------|---------|
|C00713392   |  null   |
|C00713392   | 1/1/2021|
|C00713392   | 2/1/2021|
```

I would love to get the earliest date (1/1/2021) but not null. Here is the code I tried, In result, there is no null ETD date taken but some of the Consolnumber return with the latest date. (2/1/2021)

```
Select a.ConsolNumber, a.ConsolType,a.ConsolTransport,b.Container_20F,b.Container_20R,b.Container_20H, b.Container_40F,b.DeliveryMode,c.Min(c.ETD)
FROM ConsolHeader a 
LEFT Join Containers b on a.Consolnumber = b.Consolnumber
INNER Join ConsolLegs c on a.Consolnumber = c.ConsolNumber
WHERE c.ETD is not null
GROUP BY a.ConsolNumber, a.ConsolType,a.ConsolTransport,b.Container_20F,b.Container_20R,b.Container_20H, b.Container_40F,b.DeliveryMode
```

More than that, I have more than 100k data row, kindly suggest query which will run more efficiency.

Appreciate and thanks any helps given!

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correlated subquery is a simple method:

```
SELECT ch.ConsolNumber, ch.ConsolType, ch.ConsolTransport, ch.Container_20F,
       c.Container_20R, c.Container_20H,  c.Container_40F, c.DeliveryMode,
       (SELECT MIN(cl.ETD)
        FROM ConsolLegs cl
        WHERE cl.Consolnumber = ch.Consolnumber
       ) as min_ETD
FROM ConsolHeader ch LEFT JOIN
     Containers c
     ON c.Consolnumber = ch.Consolnumber;
```

Notes:

- `MIN()` automatically ignores `NULL`s.
- Meaningful table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- This avoids the outer `GROUP BY`, which is usually a performance win.
- In most databases you want an index on `ConsoleLegs(Consolnumber, ETD)` for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
Select a.ConsolNumber, a.ConsolType, 
       a.ConsolTransport, b.Container_20F, 
       b.Container_20R, b.Container_20H, 
       b.Container_40F, b.DeliveryMode, 
       c.ETD
  FROM ConsolHeader a 
  LEFT Join Containers b on a.Consolnumber = b.Consolnumber
 INNER Join ConsolLegs c on a.Consolnumber = c.ConsolNumber
 WHERE c.ETD is not null
  AND not exists
      (select 1 from ConsolLegs cc where c.Consolnumber = cc.Consolnumber
          and cc.etd < c.etd)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get min ETD first:

```
SELECT MIN(CL.ETD) FROM ConsolLegs CL
```

then get result :

```
Select a.ConsolNumber, a.ConsolType, 
       a.ConsolTransport, b.Container_20F, 
       b.Container_20R, b.Container_20H, 
       b.Container_40F, b.DeliveryMode, 
       c.ETD
  FROM ConsolHeader a 
  LEFT Join Containers b on a.Consolnumber = b.Consolnumber
 INNER Join ConsolLegs c on a.Consolnumber = c.ConsolNumber
   AND c.ETD = (SELECT MIN(CL.ETD) FROM ConsolLegs CL)
```

if query is slow ,try add index on ConsolLegs.ETD